# Calculating total monthly precipitation values using SUMIF function to specify date window

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I've got an excel sheet with dates in one column (daily) and total precipitation values for that date in another column from 01/01/2000 to 31/12/2021.

I want to calculate the total monthly precipitation values from 2000 to 2021.

The formula I have been using after some research online was (which I was planning on iterating over the months):

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B8036,C2:C8036,"<="&DATE(2003,9,1),C2:C8036,">="&DATE(2003,9,30))
```

The values I want to sum (precipitation) are in the B column, the dates are in the C column. However, I get a zero value returned in the cell when I run the formula, even though the actual value should be 131.94.

I'm not sure what mistake I made in my formula.

Comment: Post few sample data as text.

Comment: You may want to double check the operators >= lower limit and <= upper limit

Comment: @EmmaE no worries. You can simplify the upper limit with another function, so it is easier to modify or to substitute with one cell reference for lower and upper limit: ```EOMONTH(DATE(2003,9,1),0)```

Answer (score 0):

My operators were wrong, changing it to

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B8036,C2:C8036,">="&DATE(2003,9,1),C2:C8036,"<="&DATE(2003,9,30))
```

solved my problem.